# ResourceDictionary Style Error: "type must derive from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

[GridViewColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumnheader.aspx) inherits FrameworkElement but [GridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't. Does that mean we cannot style the latter in a resource dictionary?

**Snippet in Text**

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Snippet with Error Message**

[image: Resource Dictionary Snippet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that means exactly what you said. GridViewColumn has no style. Its not an UiElement. However GridViewColumnHeader is one and it supports style.